# unistd.h and c99 on Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, c99

This simple .c file:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void test() {
   char string[40];
   gethostname(string,40);
}
```

... when compiled normally, works fine:

```
$ cc  -Wall -c -o tmp.o tmp.c
$
```

... but when compiled in C99 mode, gives a warning:

```
$ cc -Wall -std=c99 -c -o tmp.o tmp.c 
tmp.c: In function `test':
tmp.c:5: warning: implicit declaration of function `gethostname'
$
```

The resultant .o file is fine, and linking works. I'd just like to get rid of the warning. I can achieve this in a hacky way, by putting declarations in my own .h file.

What is it about C99 that means the declarations in unistd.h don't get included?
Can this be overcome, without giving up the niceness of C99?

I see the same problem for other standard libs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may need to define some macros in a particluar way to get the prototype for `gethostname()`

From `man gethostname`:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for
>   glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    gethostname(): _BSD_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500
>    sethostname(): _BSD_SOURCE || (_XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE < 500)
> ```

So:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>

void test() {
   char string[40];
   gethostname(string,40);
}
```

The gory details:

If you don't specify the `-std-c99` option, then `features.h` (which is implicitly included by `unistd.h`) will default to setting `_BSD_SOURCE` in such a way that the prototype for `gethostname()` gets included.  However, specifying `-std=c99` causes the compiler to automatically define `__STRICT_ANSI__`, which in turn causes `features.h` to not define `_BSD_SOURCE`, unless you force it with your own feature macro definition (as above).

Comment: +1 for an answer. -10 for the `#define _BSD_SOURCE`. Please please use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` or better yet in the build chain: `cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 ...`. Well, that if any kind of portability is desired.

Comment: As with my reply to Luther -- `man gethostname` on my Red Hat system makes no mention of Feature Test Macro Requirements. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 12):

`gethostname( )` is not a standard C function (it's not mentioned anywhere in the C99 standard), so the symbol is correctly not defined when compiling to the standard.

If you're using the `gcc` toolchain, use `-std=gnu99` and you'll get the behavior you want.

Alternatively, looking at `<features.h>`, it seems like you could use `-D_GNU_SOURCE` or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Although I accepted a different answer, `-std=gnu99` is the fix I actually used. Thanks.

Comment: Just ran into exactly this problem, and chose to `-std=gnu99` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Read `man gethostname`. It says in the Feature Test Macro Requirements, that `_BSD_SOURCE` (or `_XOPEN_SOURCE>500`) is required to pull gethostname from unistd.h.

Next read `man feature_test_macros`. You will find that `-std=c99` turns on `__STRICT_ANSI__` which in *turns off* `_BSD_SOURCE`. This means you can't get `gethostname` from `unistd.h` unless you define `_BSD_SOURCE` again. I usually place _GNU_SOURCE on my command line (i.e. `gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -std=c99 file.c`) for most things, which turns on `_BSD_SOURCE` as well.

P.S. The manual page contains an example program which can print the current ft-macros. You might compile and run it for some compiler settings.

Comment: None of that is in `man gethostname` on my redhat system. What system is yours on? Should I be installing extra manpages?